# alternative reaction mechanism for acetal formation from hemiacetal

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Most textbook would depict the reaction as following:
[image]
(from Organic Chemistry by Craig B. Fryhle, Scott A. Snyder, T. W. Graham Solomons)

But why wouldn't the second step be like this:
[image]

Comment: $\ce{^-OH}$ is a very strong base and therefore a bad leaving group.

Comment: the leaving group here is the protonated form of OH, which is a good leaving group?

Comment: Sorry, I misrepresented your drawing. Carbocations are generally less stable than oxonium, especially if the they have a low number of substituents bonded to them. In your proposed mechanism, the carbocation is only mono-substituted, which is very unstable and would lead to a higher activation energy.

Comment: Well yes, it could be. But I think it is oversimplistic to suggest that the electron rich oxygen right beside it plays no part.

Comment: $\ce{O-R}$ groups are electron-withdrawing, so it would just make the carbocation even less stable by making it even "more positive". I don't see a point in bringing up resonance structures considering they're non-equivalent in this case, and the major contributor (oxonium) is significantly more stable than the minor contributor (carbocation) due to octet completion and other factors mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, the mechanism you've drawn is entirely the same as the textbook mechanism (apart from the fact that your final product is missing an OR group, which I assume is an unintentional error).

The reason is because $\ce{C+-O}$ is entirely equivalent to $\ce{C=O+}$; they are two *resonance forms* of the same thing:

[image]

much like the resonance structures of benzene:

[image]

and you certainly wouldn't say that one resonance form of benzene was *different* from the other.

However, there is one difference: the $\ce{C=O+}$ resonance form is more *accurate* than the $\ce{C+-O}$ resonance form. That's because it is a larger contributor to the resonance hybrid (which in turn can be rationalised using many rules—in this case, the octet rule is relevant).

Comment: I think octet explanation would be better for OP to understand why oxonium ion ion is governing.